# How to apply a patch for a Drupal module?

Tags: 7, version-control

I'm trying to us this patch http://qa.drupal.org/pifr/test/298933

Save the patch file to the root directory of feeds module (`sites/all/modules/feeds`) then apply the patch by using git bash.

So I typed:

```
git apply -v fcollection.patch
```

and it returns the following error:

> checking patch field_collection.module...
>   error: field_collection.module: No such file directory

I hve a field_collection module installed in my site.

So what I did to experiment is to copy the patch to field_collection module folder and run the patch from that folder.

Then I got this error:

> error: patch_failed: field_collection.module:1142
>   error: field_collection.module: Patch does not apply.

How can I apply the patch successfully?

Answer (score 2):

This patch also exists at this [#1063434](http://drupal.org/node/1063434) - the original issue for the test you reference above. One easy way to apply this patch would be to use the [Drush Issue Queue](http://drupal.org/project/drush_iq) commands.

Install with:

```
drush dl drush_iq
```

Then use it like this:

```
cd /path/to/drupal/root
drush am 1063434-#40
```

Presto!  Patch applied! Then `drush-iq` will work even better if you check out the module from git (i.e. `drush dl field_collection --package-handler=git_drupalorg`).

If you don't want to use `drush-iq`, try:

```
cd /path/to/drupal/root/sites/all/modules/field_collection
wget http://drupal.org/files/field_collection-feeds_integration-1063434-40.patch
patch -Np1 < field_collection-feeds_integration-1063434-40.patch
```